# Can't store the value of a math operation. It's always 0

Tags: solidity, math, fixed-point

```
contract MyContract {
  uint public priceUSD = 1.70 * 10**8; // USD
  uint public priceEth;

   .........


  function setPrice(uint newPriceUSD) external ownerOnly() returns(uint, uint) {
    uint priceUSDInt = newPriceUSD * 10**8;
    // make a small number like 2 equal 200,000,000.

    /**
    I'm hard coding the price here just to debug it
    but eventually, I'd be calling Chainlink 
    like this...
    (int price,) = getLatestPrice();
    **/

    int price = 132556000000;

    // this like evaluates to 
    // 150879.62823259603
    // I'm attempting to set it to the state variable priceEth
    priceEth = priceUSDInt / uint(price) * 10**8;

    // storing the number to state variable
    priceUSD = txtPriceUSDInt;

    // return both new prices
    return (newTxtPriceUSD, priceEth);
  }

  function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int, uint8) {
    (
      ,int price,,,
    ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData(); // Chainlink call

    uint8 decimals = priceFeed.decimals();
    return (price, decimals);
  }

  .........
}
```

Whenever `setPrice()` is called with e.g. `setPrice(2)`, the intention is to set a new price in USD and in Eth.
But I can't seem to ever set `priceEth`. It's always 0.

I'm really new to fixed-point math. It could be I'm doing something totally wrong here. But, when I use the Remix debugger and type of the result of `txtPriceUSDInt / uint(price) * 10**8;` I get a non zero number.
But when I check the value of `priceEth`, it's always 0.

I'm not sure I'm doing something wrong with fixed-point arithmetic or something else. If anyone has any pointers?

Comment: What is `setTxtPrice`???

Comment: Plus, you obviously seem to be missing the fact that division in solidity is **integer-division**, meaning that if `x < y` then `x / y == 0`.

Comment: "I'm not sure I'm doing something wrong with fixed-point arithmetic" - in fixed-point arithmetic, `2 / 132556000000 == 0`.

Comment: Oops. It's suppose to be `setPrice`. I changed it. And yes, still figuring out solidity-math hence why I asked the question :)

Comment: You seem to be aware of the term 'fixed-point', so where exactly is the problem? Do you understand what *integer-division* means?